# farsi character in knitr

Tags: r, character-encoding, knitr

In R 3.3.1, I'm using knitr 1.13, and I'm having trouble recognizing Farsi characters. I save the following code in a file called `test.Rnw` and then run `knit("test.Rnw")`,  but the Farsi characters change to `?????` in output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}%package for type Farsi in LaTex
\begin{document}
این یک متن آزمایشی است
<<model>>=
fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
@
برای آزمایش داریم:
\Sexpr{coef(fit)[2]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot even compile your document: You need to include `\settextfont` to load a Farsi font, such as “XB Niloofar”. Then it should work (although the model code is wrongly typeset because you didn’t reset the text direction to left-to-right). Just to verify: which operating system are you on? R’s Windows version has issues with character encoding. In addition, ensure that your document is loaded using the correct encoding by knitr. Can you have a look at the `tex` file that is being produced? Does that contain the correct characters?

Comment: OK I set farsi font but output TeX file contain ????  My operation system is windows 7 64bit

Comment: In that case, ensure that your Rnw file is encoded as UTF-8, and set that encoding explicitly when knitting the file.

Comment: I go to file-->Save with Encoding and save my file with UTF-8 and then run knit("test.Rnw",encoding="UTF-8") and this worked. Thank you

Comment: Awesome, I’ll add an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure that the file is saved in UTF-8 encoding
2. On most operating systems, that’s enough, since UTF-8 is the system’s default encoding anyway. Especially on Windows, you additionally need to specify the encoding when knitting, e.g.:

   ```
   knit('filename.rnw', encoding = 'UTF-8')
   ```

Futhermore, you need explicitly handle reading direction of your text: Farsi is right-to-left, but the (Western) source code requires left-to-right text direction. This needs to be set explicitly in the code using e.g. `\(un)setLTR`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
% Set a font for the text
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
این یک متن آزمایشی است
\setLTR
<<model>>=
fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
@
\unsetLTR
برای آزمایش داریم:
\Sexpr{coef(fit)[2]}
\end{document}
```

You could also use a Knitr hook to set this automatically for each code chunk. You could probably adapt [example 74](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/c1894e02d43e013048d42ba9b86a7fec1200ae15/074-example-environment.Rnw) for this:

```
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(ltr = function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) '\\setLTR' else '\\unsetLTR'
})
@
```

Now you can write a code chunk as follows:

```
<<model, ltr=TRUE>>
fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
@
```

No need for manual `\setLTR`…`\unsetLTR` any more.

Comment: I have another problem:( code chunks are Right to Left in output, While it should be left to right

Comment: @aminroshani As mentioned in my previous comments, you need to set this explicitly — see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.